# What's the sutta/source for Devadatta's attempt to kill the Buddha with the drunken war elephant Nalagiri?

Tags: buddha

Is there Sutta reference for Devadatta's third attempt to kill the Buddha with drunken elephant Nalagiri as mentioned in Life of the Buddha?
https://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/buddhism/lifebuddha/2_5lbud.htm

Comment: A story in the Cullavagga of the Vinaya Pitaka relates how the Buddha's envious cousin, Devadatta, tried to kill him by releasing a notoriously ferocious elephant called Nalagiri at him in the streets of Rajagaha. The Buddha is said to have subdued it by exercising metta and karuna, so that the elephant lowered its trunk and stopped before the Buddha. Hiuen-Tsang refers to a stupa at the place where this is said to have happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now at that time there was a fierce elephant in Rājagaha, a man-slayer, called Nālāgiri. Then Devadatta, having entered Rājagaha, having gone to the elephant stable, spoke thus to the mahouts: “We, my good fellows, are relations of the king. We are competent to put in a high position one occupying a lowly position and to bring about an increase in food and wages. Well now, good fellows, when the recluse Gotama is coming along this carriage road, then, having let loose this elephant, Nālāgiri, bring him down this carriage road.”

https://suttacentral.net/pli-tv-kd17/en/horner-brahmali